# Custom Close Reason - Musical Question

Tags: discussion, topic-scope, close-reasons

Should we have a custom close reason for musician related questions?  If so, what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Sound Design is a site for sound design and production professionals and enthusiasts.  Music related sound design that would be done by musicians is off topic as this is not a Q/A site for musicians.

While musicians also design sounds, it is a different style with different requirements and needs than what is covered here.  You may have better luck at [Musical Practice & Performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As said in the meta discussion, I would suggest removing the enthusiasts part.

Comment: @EMV - depending on how you define professional I might have to leave then.  I am more than capable of doing multiple forms of production sound at a professional level, but I don't often get paid for sound since I get paid more for doing other things and have a limited amount of time in the day.  I agree we need to be careful of the description and don't want home audio questions or audiophile content, but a large portion of our user base does not work full time in the industry nor do they intend to.

Comment: I see your point. So how can we describe people doing sound design at a professional level, without ruling out those that are not doing it full-time or as a paid job? I don't think "enthusiasts" covers this.

Comment: @EMV - yes, and made even more difficult since phrases like experienced are far too variable to give a concrete line for on or off topic, though, honestly, if we could rule out all the audiophile and home theater and music questions, we'd be much closer to where we want to be.  That's probably 80% of the bad questions right now.  It's also easy enough to write generic questions and answers to cover a lot of the basic stuff and then close overly simple questions as duplicates.  Most beginner questions are either too broad or generically answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have the privilege scale sorted out, let's see what happens over the next 30 - 45 days, I'm going to run some queries to see what gets closed (and why) - folks can utilize the 'other' custom close reason to indicate that's why they're closing (in fact, they're welcome to use the very text you came up with).

At *that* time, I'd like to come back to this, and start formulating the close reasons we see a clear, repetitive use for.

Comment: Sounds good.  I'm pretty sure that it will still end up being one as it has appeared to be the single most common close reason other than being "too basic," which I have no idea how to make a workable standard reason for since why it is too basic tends to vary.  But it will be nice to have actual numbers on the close reasons too and see the broader community stance now that more people can VTC.